# ASP.NET Core: DI Service with conditions

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-2.2

I want to register my service class ADManager in Startup. But the class have a string parameters in the constructor, and the instantiation depends if the user is on the same domain as the webb application.

```
// Constructor
public ADManager(
    string ADDomain, bool isSameDomain = true,
    string username = null, string password = null)
```

Here is how I make a instance of the class manually, if is same domain:

```
var adManager = new ADManager(_authenticationSettings.AdDomain, _isSameDomain);
```

But if _isSameDomain equal false then it have to be created like this:

```
var adManager = new ADManager(
    _authenticationSettings.AdDomain, _isSameDomain, Input.Username, Input.Password);
```

Comment: When do you know if the user is of the same domain or not? During runtime, right?

Comment: Yeah, I have to call another service to check the user´s IP and compare it to the servers network address.

Comment: @Olof84 Use factory delegate overload when registering the service. within the factory delegate you can perform your check and instantiate as needed. Where is `Input` taken from?

Comment: It seems you are trying to inject *runtime data* into your application component. This is a bad practice, as explained [here](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2015/code-smell-injecting-runtime-data-into-components/).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Steven, you are right. I removed the injection from startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the factory overload of `AddScoped`. The lambda you pass as the factory will be run each time the service is instantiated, which in a scoped lifetime, will be roughly every request.

```
services.AddScoped<ADManager>(p =>
{
    // use `p` to get any other services, i.e. `p.GetRequiredService<Foo>()`
    return new ADManager(...);
});
```

Just be aware, that while in normal operation, there should always be an associated request, it will be possible to, depending on how you use the service, that it will be operating outside the request pipeline. For example, if you attempted to pull it out in a singleton:

```
using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
{
    var adManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ADManager>();
    // HttpContext could be null in this scope
}
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I hesitated to set this as answer, since I realized my question was wrong to begin with. I should not try to make an instance of the class in startup since it might requires user name and password in it´s constructor.